# Edit Page not displaying Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Any help is greatly appreciated!,

Everything was going great until I stumbled across this :(

When I click edit on my display table, It goes to the edit vue putting a 0 in my id text field but the rest of the form is blank?

What I have:

```
 public ActionResult EditProduct(int? id)  
 {
    Product prod = new Product();

    return View(prod); 
 }
```

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are creating a new product and then sending that to the view, so it will be blank and have a zero as the id.

You need to retrieve your product and then pass it to the view. Maybe like this:

```
public ActionResult EditProduct(int? id)  
{
    Product prod = _productRepository.Get(id);// code to retrieve product from database
    if (prod != null)
    {
       return View(prod); 
    }
    else
    {
       return RedirectToAction("Error"); // or whatever...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! appreciate your help! But I'v been trying to do that repository.get all night but cant figure out how to do it :S?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load your product from your data store by id instead of creating a new instance. Something like:

```
return View(db.Products.Find(id))
```

A great place to start with MVC is http://www.asp.net/mvc. There are plenty of tutorials for data driven mvc web sites.

Comment: Thanks! could you give me an example of createing a repository So I can use GetID etc... you link it to your controller by doing ProductRepository repository = new ProductRepository() Correct?

Comment: Well, you have to implement ProductRepository, then you can instantiate it any way you'd like. I would recommend the "Getting Started with EF using MVC" tutorial at http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

To do your repository, create an interface named IProduct with a method Get, GetAll, Save, etc. Your repository class implementation ie ProductRepository.cs that implements IProductRepository has a reference to your ObjectContext (or DbContext is using ef 4.1)

Some prefer to have a generic IRepository interface - but as it was said to me 'a generic repository is a fairy tale'

Once you have that, create

```
YourRepository repository = new Repository(); //Some choose to pass in a context or inject one via unity, ninject, etc. this is a basic example.
```

Your repository has a method

```
private YourContextName _context = new YourContextName();
public Product Get(int productId)
{
  return _context.Products.Where(o=>o.ProductId=productId).Single();
}
```

Thats all there is to it. Of course there are more advanced implementations but it is fairly basic.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/20/using-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ImplRepositoryPatternEF.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx